# How to force increasing coeffiecients constraint to np.linalg.lstsq

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, linear-regression, least-squares

I have a linear system of equations

[image]

and I need to find x that minimizes the least square error

[image]

with the constraint of increasing positive values for the elements in x;

[image]

Using np.linalg.lstsq function (numpy version '1.14.2', python '3.6.5') I cannot set any constrain to the coefficients, i. e.

```py
>>> A = np.array([[4.737, 4.673, 4.664, 4.614, 4.614],
       [4.491, 4.377, 4.38 , 4.401, 4.406],
       [2.496, 1.689, 1.68 , 1.62 , 1.64 ],
       [3.461, 3.136, 2.816, 2.723, 2.551],
       [2.814, 2.4  , 2.444, 2.423, 2.436]])

>>> y = np.array([4.90909091, 4.86363636, 1.86363636, 2.63636364, 3.63636364])

>>> x = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)
>>> x[0]
array([  1.27108078, -22.41177441,  20.48017772,  37.03891117,
       -35.2836762 ])
```

While I'd like to have increasing values for c[0]

I know I may also use scipy.optimize.nnls in order to obtain positive coefficients, but this will not deal with the 'incresing coefficient' constraint.

Comment: I think your problem is not really a classic linear optimization problem (it is not linear). I would use a QP (quadratic programming) solver. These are readily available for use with Python

Comment: Yes sorry, I actually meant that I have a linear system of equations.
Thanks, I'll give a look to QP solver.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the result you get without doing anything special, then reorder your the columns of your system so that the new solution, actually the same as the first one, shows the coeficients in increasing order.